# How to use db context in custom logger provider .NET 6

Tags: c#, api, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I can`t add database context into custom logger provider in Program.cs

I try code below:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<EFDataContext>();
var app = builder.Build();
builder.Logging.AddProvider(new CustomLoggerProvider(app.Services.GetRequiredService<EFDataContext>()));
```

but get an error (and can`t use singleton for dbContext due to options): 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'eSchronisko.Server.Domain.EFDataContext' from root provider.'.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend to skip reinventing the wheel and use an existing library which provides logging into database. For example [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) which has several sinks allowing to write to different databases.
2. If you still considering reinventing the wheel for some reason - still better look into extending some existing logger library then starting from scratch.
3. If you do not want to build on top of the existing library - I strongly recommend prevent building app several times and leverage DI in the logger provider via the following approach ([see the custom logger docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider#create-the-custom-logger)):

   ```cs
   public class CustomLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
   {
       private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

       public CustomLoggerProvider(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
       {
           _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
       }

       public void Dispose(){} // todo

       public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName) => new CustomLogger(categoryName, _scopeFactory);
   }

   public sealed class CustomLogger : ILogger
   {
       private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

       public CustomLogger(string category, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
       {
           _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
       }

       public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull => default!;

       public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true; // todo

       public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
       {
           using var serviceScope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
           var provider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
           // resolve scoped service, for example db context: 
           var someService = provider.GetRequiredService<SomeService>(); 
           // use someService...
       }
   }
   ```

   and registration:

   ```cs
   builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(new ServiceDescriptor(
       typeof(ILoggerProvider),
       typeof(CustomLoggerProvider),
       ServiceLifetime.Singleton
   ));
   ```
4. Addressing the initial problem - to access context from the root scope you need either change the context lifetime scope (default - Scoped, though personally I would not recommend changing it in general case) or create a scope manually - see [this answer](https://github.com/serilog/serilog).